# How do I make sure that the total prints a value and not just 0

Tags: c++, variables, output, logic

The program has no errors but everytime I run the program the total comes out as 0 despite "qty" and "cost" having values. How do I write this in a way so that total will actually output the number calculated by multiplying quantity and cost?

`````
{
    char itemAnswer = 'a';
    double qty = 0;
    double cost = 0;
    double total = qty*cost;
    double payment = 0;
    double change = payment-total;
    
    
    std::cout << "Which item would you like to buy?" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a. Notebook | b. Pencil | c. Ballpen" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> itemAnswer;
    

        if(itemAnswer == 'a' || itemAnswer == 'A')
         {
            double cost = 15.50;

            std::cout << "You chose notebook" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Enter quantity: ";
            std::cin >> qty;
            std::cout << "You added " << qty << " of notebook/s into your cart." << std::endl;

            std::cout << "Your total will be " << total << " Php" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Enter payment: ";
            std::cin >> payment;

                while (payment < qty * cost)
                {
                    std::cout << "You did not pay enough money" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "Enter money again: ";
                    std::cin >> payment;
                }
                if (payment >= qty * cost)
                {
                    std::cout << "You paid " << payment << " Php" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "Your change is " << payment - qty * cost << " Php" << std::endl;
                } ````
`````

Comment: `double total = qty*cost;` does the computation where it is placed, `total` doesn't change afterward when you modify `qty` or `cost`

Comment: `auto total = [&]() { return qty * cost; };` with `total()` usage might solve your issue. Not sure it is the way to go for beginner though.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't do symbolic computations, instead it takes the current values of variables - i.e. when you write

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = a + b;
```

and later on you assign different values to `a` and `b`, for example

```
a = 1;
b = 3;
```

`c` will still keep its value of 0, and not automatically update to 4, unless you do a `c = a + b;` *again* to after changing `a` and `b` as above (or you can move the initial `int c = a + b;` to the place where you actually need `c`'s value, if you don't need it above anyway).